Parse Continuation Lines in ANTLR
I am writing a parser in ANTLR using C# for a language which allows a line of syntax to be split over multiple lines using the back slash to indicate there are subsequent lines. This is further complication by the ability to add a comment to any line of code. e.g I can write something like
If ((A = B) AND \:Check A and B
    (C <> D))    :Check C and D
   Add 1 Count
End

i.e the If statement is split over two lines but also has a comment on both lines. The break can be anywhere in the line of syntax, so could equally write
If ((A = B) \:Check A and B
   AND (C <> D))    :Check C and D
   Add 1 Count
End

Currently I am treating the back slash as white space and ignoring it.
WS : [ ()\\\t\r\n\f;]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);

My definition for a boolean is
// Boolean Expressions
booleanCondition        : booleanExpression | '(' booleanExpression ')';
booleanExpression       : expression ('='|'<>'|'<'|'>') expression ((AND|OR|'&&'|'||') booleanExpression)*;

and a comment is
COMMENT                 : ':'+ ~[:=\r\n]*;

When I parse the example code it almost gets things right, but misses the first comment completely and parses the second comment as a ErrorNode. Is there any way I can do this in ANTLR without writing some form of pre-parser?
Any advice would be much appreciated

This seems to work:
parse
 : if_stat EOF
 ;

if_stat : 'If' expression command 'End';

command
 : 'Add' expression ID
 ;

expression
 : '(' expression ')'
 | expression ('=' | '<>' | '<' | '>') expression
 | expression ('AND' | 'OR' | '&&' | '||') expression
 | ID
 | NUMBER
 ;

LINE_CONTINUATION : '\\' COMMENT? '\r'? '\n' -> channel(HIDDEN);
COMMENT           : ':' ~[\r\n]+             -> channel(HIDDEN);
WS                : [ \t\r\n\f]+             -> channel(HIDDEN);
NUMBER            : [0-9]+;
ID                : [a-zA-Z]+;

which parses:
If ((A = B) AND \:Check A and B
    (C <> D))    :Check C and D
   Add 1 Count
End

as follows:


Perfect - thanks so much!
